# Query Autocomplete limit to selected country (not Places Autocomplete with map)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Is there any way of using Query Autocomplete (not Places Autocomplete with map) to limit propositions only from one country (or multiple countries in general)? The solution with setting map center and radius with restrict bounds doesn't solve the problem. Is there any URL parameter for this but not mentioned in docs? I don't mean parameter 'types' to limit results to countries, but rather to propose cities from one selected country?

I've followed these docs to find a solution: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query

Comment: This is a pertinent question. I wonder why other people are down-voting it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering if there's a ***multiple*** country filter feature in Query Autocomplete? If so, we have an entry for this feature request in our **Google Issue Tracker**.

We would like to warmly invite you to view the issue in the Issue Tracker, and to star it to register your interest. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides us with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to our customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

You can view and star the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/123935011

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding this issue, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there.

Comment: Thank you very much for feedback! It would be great if Google provide that option. Actually I'm just parsing propositions manually that are not in my countries range and it's a bit cumbersome :)